# How see source code of imported class or function in atom editor?

Tags: python-3.x, django, atom-editor

In IDE PyCharm I saw a opportunity to see source code of imported functions or classes.
How can I do the same thing in my favourite atom editor?
I sure that it has a special package but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking to grab the same package. I did some research and the action is called "go to definition".

The package you have to install in atom is

"goto-definition"

If you want to install it in command line for atom:

```
$ apm install goto-definition
```

When it is installed, in mac. Simply while selection the module import, command + option + click = go to definition

It will show you the definition.

Here, the link of the package repo:

https://atom.io/packages/goto-definition